# Can't update with yum, seeing error PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host" Alternatives?

Tags: system-administration, yum, rhel, rhel5

I'm trying to update a PHP module using yum, but am getting an error.

Here's what I am trying and seeing :

```
 yum install php-ldap
```

result :

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security,
          : subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-ldap.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6_2.6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package       Arch        Version              Repository                 Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 php-ldap      x86_64      5.3.3-3.el6_2.6      rhel-x86_64-server-6       36 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 36 k
Installed size: 0
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:


Error Downloading Packages:
  php-ldap-5.3.3-3.el6_2.6.x86_64: failed to retrieve getPackage/php-ldap-5.3.3-          3.el6_2.6.x86_64.rpm from rhel-x86_64-server-6
error was [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host"
```

I really need to install this module tonight.  What are my alternatives ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that our Network Admin had blocked access to the internet from that machine.  Yum was just timing out.